# How to find number of arguments that come into a constructor in node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, object, constructor

I have a constructor in node.js as follows.

```
function Tree() {
  //Redirect to other functions depends upon argument count.
}
```

And i created objects like

```
var theTree = new Tree('Redwood');
var theTree = new Tree('Redwood',5);
var theTree = new Tree('Redwood',10,"USA");
```

My requirement is that i want to redirect to different functions depending upon the number of arguments that came to constructor. How can I find the number of arguments ?

Comment: arguments.length inside function Tree() should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply use the `arguments.length` variable.

For more info you can read about the *arguments* object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 1):

There is an arguments variable in every function.

```
function Tree() {
  console.log(arguments)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a local variable arguments that contains all the values that are passed to a function.

```
arguments.length
```

this will give the count.